# Como formatar números em Lua?

Tags: lua, formatação

Gostaria de saber como formatar a variável:

```
local n = 100000000
```

Para que retorne assim:

```
100.000.000
```

Separados por pontos, alguém sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function dot_string(s)
    -- não precisamos de pontinhos para números até 999
    if s:len() <= 3 then
        return s
    end 

    -- senão, colocamos o pontinho no último grupo de 3 e repetimos o processo para o que sobrou
    return dot_string(s:sub(1, -4)) .. "." .. s:sub(-3)
end 

function dot_number(n)
    -- TODO: n < 0
    -- TODO: n != int(n)
    -- TODO: n grande
    return dot_string(tostring(n))
end
```

Se o n for negativo, fracionário ou gigante, o tostring() vai fazer lambança, mas caso contrário a função atende o que você pediu (pelo menos os dois primeiros casos são fáceis de tratar com `if`s na dot_number antes de chamar a dot_string).

Exemplo:

```
print(dot_number(0))
print(dot_number(10))
print(dot_number(210))
print(dot_number(3210))
print(dot_number(43210))
print(dot_number(543210))
print(dot_number(6543210))
print(dot_number(10000000000000))

print()
-- …alguns casos que não funcionam…
print(dot_number(-123))
print(dot_number(12.5))
print(dot_number(100000000000000))
```

Saída:

```
0
10
210
3.210
43.210
543.210
6.543.210
10.000.000.000.000

-.123
1.2.5
1e.+14
```

Comment: Acho que seria legal fazer o tratamento de casos *excepcionais* em que a função falha, por exemplo, números muito extensos, etc.

Comment: Eu dei +1 pra você, mas eu acho que só cabe atualizar se o @vodka responder pra quê ele quer usar essa função. Eu não quis tratar os casos negativo e fracionário porque eu não sei a aplicação dele. Se for e.g. pra exibir valores monetários, números negativos têm que aparecer como `(123)`, não `-123`; números decimais têm que aparecer limitados a duas casas decimais, e números ≥ 10^14 têm que lançar erros — como Lua usa `double`s para representar números, eles têm precisão pior que centavos.

Answer (score 4):

A forma proposta pela [página **Formatting Numbers** - lua-users.org](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FormattingNumbers) é usar a [função `string.gsub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/pt/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) da seguinte forma:

```
function formatarNumero(valor)
  local formatado = valor
  while true do  
                                          -- O "." entre "%1" e "%2" é o separador
    formatado, n = string.gsub(formatado, "^(-?%d+)(%d%d%d)", '%1.%2') 
    if ( n ==0 ) then
      break
    end
  end
  return formatado
end
```

A expressão [*`(^-?\d+)(\d\d\d)`*](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%5E-%3F%5Cd%2B%29%28%5Cd%5Cd%5Cd%29) basicamente irá quebrar o valor em pedaços graças ao quantificador `?` que vai repetir *zero* ou *uma* vez, tantas vezes que for possível satisfazê-la.

Uma forma alternativa usando a [função `string.match`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/pt/manual.html#pdf-string.match):

```
function formatarNumero(valor) -- Créditos http://richard.warburton.it
    local esquerda, num, direita = string.match(valor,'^([^%d]*%d)(%d*)(.-)$')
    return esquerda..(num:reverse():gsub('(%d%d%d)', '%1.'):reverse())..direita
end
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
print(formatarNumero(1))          -- 1
print(formatarNumero(10))         -- 10
print(formatarNumero(100))        -- 100
print(formatarNumero(1000))       -- 1.000
print(formatarNumero(10000))      -- 10.000
print(formatarNumero(100000))     -- 100.000
print(formatarNumero(1000000))    -- 1.000.000
print(formatarNumero(10000000))   -- 10.000.000
print(formatarNumero(100000000))  -- 100.000.000
print(formatarNumero(1000000000)) -- 1.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-123))       -- -123
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/jP2wvL)

### Atualização

As funções acima falham ao formatar números muito extensos como *100000000000000*, para resolver este problema, será necessário utilizar a [biblioteca `lbc`](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lbc) criada pelo [**lhf**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1642/lhf), que é baseada no [GNU `bc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/) para processamento numérico de precisão arbitrária.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
require "bc"

function formatarNumero(valor)
  numero = bc.number(valor)
  local formatado = tostring(numero)
  while true do
    formatado, n = string.gsub(formatado, "^(-?%d+)(%d%d%d)", '%1.%2')
    if ( n ==0 ) then
      break
    end
  end
  return formatado
end
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
print(formatarNumero(1))            -- 1
print(formatarNumero(10))           -- 10
print(formatarNumero(100))          -- 100
print(formatarNumero(1000))         -- 1.000
print(formatarNumero(10000))        -- 10.000
print(formatarNumero(100000))       -- 100.000
print(formatarNumero(1000000))      -- 1.000.000
print(formatarNumero(10000000))        -- 10.000.000
print(formatarNumero(100000000))       -- 100.000.000
print(formatarNumero(1000000000))      -- 1.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(10000000000))     -- 10.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(100000000000))    -- 100.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(1000000000000))   -- 1.000.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(10000000000000))  -- 10.000.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(100000000000000))     -- 100.000.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(1000000000000000))    -- 1.000.000.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(10000000000000000))   -- 10.000.000.000.000.000

print(formatarNumero(-1))            -- -1
print(formatarNumero(-10))           -- -10
print(formatarNumero(-100))          -- -100
print(formatarNumero(-1000))         -- -1.000
print(formatarNumero(-10000))        -- -10.000
print(formatarNumero(-100000))       -- -100.000
print(formatarNumero(-1000000))      -- -1.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-10000000))        -- -10.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-100000000))       -- -100.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-1000000000))      -- -1.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-10000000000))     -- -10.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-100000000000))    -- -100.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-1000000000000))   -- -1.000.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-10000000000000))  -- -10.000.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-100000000000000))     -- -100.000.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-1000000000000000))    -- -1.000.000.000.000.000
print(formatarNumero(-10000000000000000))   -- -10.000.000.000.000.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function func(number)
    local number = number
    local decimal = number - math.floor(number)
    decimal = tonumber(tostring(decimal):sub(3, string.len(decimal)))
    number = tostring(math.floor(number)):reverse()
    for _ = 3, #number, 4 do
            number = number:sub(1, _) .. "." .. number:sub(_ + 1, #number)
    end
    return number:reverse() .. (decimal and "," .. decimal or "")
end
```

Comment: `local number = number`  é redundante. Converter `decimal` para número também...